# HTML Canvas Img Scaling Somehow does Not Work

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, resize

I'm trying to scale a local image through Javascript like this:

```
function resizeImage(file, func){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        var factor = img.width/800;
        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = img.height/factor;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.scale(factor, factor);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        func(canvas.toDataURL());
    }
    img.src = file.dataload; //file is an json-Object and dataload a dataURI
}
```

Somehow the data returned by canvas.toDataURL() is not resized in any way.
I double checked that canvas.width and canvas.height are the correct computed sizes.

Any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `scale()` method as it only affects what is being drawn to the canvas bitmap, not the bitmap itself (the `drawImage()` will in any case scale the image properly).

You need to scale the canvas using the `width` and `height` properties. These are basis for the dimension you get with `toDataURL()`.

```
var factor = img.width/800;
var scale = 2;
canvas.width = 800 * scale; 
canvas.height = img.height/factor * scale;
```

If you need the canvas *element* to stay the same on screen apply CSS to it as well:

```
canvas.style.width = 800 + 'px'; 
canvas.style.height = img.height/factor + 'px';
```